# signal local to process scope

Tags: vhdl, grammar, semantics

I have often wondered why a VHDL `variable` can be declared both on the `process` as well as the `architecture` (as `shared`) level, while a `signal` can only be declared on the `architecture` level - even if it is just used in the scope of a single `process`.

Declaring *things* (e.g. `signals` or `variable`s) in a scope as narrow as possible and as close to the place they are being used, does increase the readability quite a bit in my opinion.

Hence my question: Is there any reason inherent to the design of the VHDL language, why the following can not be done?

```
architecture does_not_compile of test is
    signal a, d : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 

    -- This would work, but does not need to be here:
    -- signal c : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
begin
    process (clk)
        variable b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 

        -- This would be nice, but is not permitted:
        signal c : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
    begin 
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then
                b := foo_operation(a); -- could just be used to store an intermediary value
                c <= bar_operation(b); -- could e.g. be a pipeline register
                d <= baz_operation(c); -- the "output register" of this process
            end if;
    end process;

    -- somewhere else: 
    a <= input_xyz;
    output_xyz <= d
end architecture;
```

*And just in case: I **do** understand the difference between `signal` and `variable`...*

Comment: You could wrap your process or multiple processes in a block or generate statement to declare signals with a smaller scope.

Comment: Perhaps you should go to http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/WebHome, join the working group, and advocate for the addition.  I see no reason not to do it, and while @Paebbels method would be a verbose way to handle a process, it would not work at all in a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason inherent to the design of the VHDL language, why the following can not be done?

```
process (clk)
    variable b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 

    -- This would be nice, but is not permitted:
    signal c : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
begin
```

(Declare a signal in a process.)

How would you resolve visibility?

A process statement is a declarative region.

All concurrent statements have equivalent processes or block statement equivalents and equivalent processes, elaborated for simulation.

All those processes are separate declarative regions, albeit you're apparently only advocating allowing signal declarations as explicitly declared process declarative items.

Function calls are expressions, procedure calls are statements, concurrent procedure calls have equivalent processes for simulation.

A signal can only communicate between sequential statements in the same process by encountering a wait statement. A signal today would be declared in an enclosing declarative region (a block declarative item or a port declaration) or made visible by a use clause when declared as a package declarative item.

Note you can use wait statements and variables to the same effect internally to a process.

Where it get's interesting is  using signals for their intended purpose - communicating between processes.

Case 1

Two or more processes in the same declarative region which also has a signal of the same name declared as in one process.  Which signal declaration do other processes use?

Case 2

Three or more processes in the same declarative region with two of them declaring the same signal name.  Which declaration does the third or other processes use?

Signal declarations in a process  don't seem resolvable from a visibility perspective.

Consider how to extend the scope of a signal declaration to the enclosing declarative region by using a 'shared' signal declaration.  That could resolve the second case if only one signal declaration were shared but not both and no declaration was visible in the enclosing declarative region. It doesn't address the first case at all, and selected names aren't allowed to use a process as a prefix (and would require an instantiation name if they were, incidentally requiring a process statement be labelled).

How would this be useful?  It's ambiguous.

VHDL restricts where signals can be declared so that the visibility rules provide at most one possible declaration. The scope of a declaration doesn't extend into enclosing or adjacent declarative regions.

And as a cure instead of using paebbel's block statement you could also declare signals as package declarative items made privately visible by use clauses in particular processes.

Comment: The issue of shadowing / name-resolution ambiguity is indeed an argument against it in a language as "strict" as VHDL. Although the `block` based solution suggested by @Paebbels shows that such scope resolution is already done. - And thanks for correcting the question (I actually meant to write `variable` there; adjusted now).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to do it and no you cannot and I don't believe VHDL2008 is fixing it (but a lot of awesome things are being fixed/added in VHDL2008). You can use always true generate statements (as already mentioned in a comment). Although if your using always true generate statements your module is probably to big and you should break it up.

I did just want to point out that you can still use/implement your pipeline register in a variable. if you swap the d and c assignments around. I know it's not as nice but I do use it occasionally and it synthesizes fine. Variables keep their values between consecutive runs of the process.

```
architecture does_not_compile of test is
    signal a, d : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
begin
    process (clk)
        variable b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
        variable c : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
    begin 
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then
                b := foo_operation(a); -- could just be used to store an intermediary value
                d <= baz_operation(c); -- the "output register" of this process
                c := bar_operation(b); -- could e.g. be a pipeline
            end if;
    end process;

    -- somewhere else: 
    a <= input_xyz;
    output_xyz <= d
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the approach for pipelining with variables for completeness. However, inserting or removing a pipeline-stage requires error-prone reshuffling and leads to hard to read 'upside-down' dataflow. Hence, this was actually one of the reasons that lead to this question in the first place.